# Initial conditions of a second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

This may look like a physics problem, but everything *physical* is explained below and I am looking for a mathematical solution.

[image: RLC]

An RLC circuit (pictured above) is governed by two equations:
$$ -iR=-L \frac{dj}{dt} = \frac{q}{C}+V(t) $$
$$\frac{dq}{dt}=i+j$$

q satisfies the equation:
$$\frac{d^2q}{dt^2}+\frac{1}{RC}\frac{dq}{dt}+\frac{1}{LC}q=-\frac{1}{R}\frac{dV}{dt}-\frac{1}{L}V $$
The system is held in a steady state (i.e. $\frac{dq}{dt}=0$ and $V(t)=\frac{Q}{C}$) for negative time. At t=0 the voltage is switched off and $V(t) = 0$ for $t \geq 0$.

**Question: how to derive the initial conditions for the system, i.e. $q(0)=Q$ and $\dot{q}(0)=\frac{Q}{RC}$ ?**

My attempt: to calculate the charge in the steady state (just before t=0), I can set all derivatives with respect to time to 0. Then I get $V=-\frac{C}{q}$ and I can define $Q=-\frac{C}{V}$. I don't know how to handle the discontinuity at t=0 to obtain $\dot{q}(0)$ though.

Comment: How do you know you should get the initial condition $\dot{q}(0)=\frac{Q}{RC}$?

Comment: @JiK, this is what I am supposed to derive and I got it from a problem sheet. If V(0) is discontinuous, wouldn't $\dot{q}(0)$ be discontinuous as well?

Comment: Oh, you're right. If $V$ is discontinuous, that means the voltage over the resistor changes abruptly, and thus $i$ is discontinuous and thus $\dot{q}$ is indeed discontinuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the physical condition that $j$ is continuous everywhere. Using that, you get $j(0^+)=0$, and thus $\dot{q}(0^+)=i(0^+)=\dots$.

Or without thinking more about physics, you can argue that a discontinuity of $j$ at $0$ would mean that $\frac{dj}{dt}$ had a $\delta$ peak, which is incorrect because $-L\frac{dj}{dt}$ equals something that cannot have a delta peak even in the approximation that $V$ changes abruptly.